# Центировать текст в ячейке

Tags: ms-word

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

У меня есть таблица небольшая, иногда приходится несколько значений привязывать к одной ячейке, к одному названию - так вот, насколько я понимаю большая таблица которая обьеденена с именем `Name` по прежнему считает что там две строчки, так вот вопрос - как центировать текст ровно в ячейке, что бы визуально `Name` был ровно в центре, а не казалось что вписан в первую строчку.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если это не программный вопрос (не увидел никакой конкретики), то вероятное решение:
Выделить ячейку Name -> Свойства -> Ячейка -> Вертикальное выравнивание (по центру)

Comment: Спасибо большое, нашёл =).

Answer (score 0):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Кнопка `Выровнять по центру`, при выделении текста.